# Properly storing objects in array

Tags: vb.net

I know this is probably a dumb question, but it's a really big deal so I want to make sure I do it properly. Is this okay?

```
Dim obj as MyObj
Dim objarr as New Arraylist

For x as Integer = 1 to 10
     obj = New MyObj
     obj.SomeValue = x
     objarr.add(obj)
Next
```

Will the array contain all separate objects or will they all contain the same object? Am I making mistakes by using the same MyObj object to add to the list?
Thanks

Comment: As a side note, you may want to look into using `Generic.List(Of MyObj)` instead, for a strong typed List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually declare a collecting list outside of your loop. My take on it:

```
Dim objarr as New Generic.List(Of MyObj)
For x as Integer = 1 to 10
  objarr.add(New MyObj With {.SomeValue = x})
Next
```

And here is a class I used for testing purposes:

```
Private Class MyObj
  Public Property SomeValue As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Very nice code. Obviously you are waaaayy ahead of me lol. The Of keyword throws me for a loop. I guess it is better to use Of so you don't have to DirectCast in the future to get the object? Why use "property" when i can just do public x as integer???

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle: Generics also give you the benefit of catching most compile time errors, exactly because there is no runtime casting. .NET framework seems to have better support for properties, than fields. IIRC, their default data binding cannot map on fields, so you need to use properties. In your case either would work fine.

Comment: If you make it a public field (e.g. `Public SomeValue As Integer`), you have no control over its getter and setter.  So, if you need to ever do that, you would have to change it from a field to a property.  When you do that, it changes the public interface of the class (because fields and properties are handled very differently in IL).  Therefore, any other assemblies that use the class would need to be recompiled as well or else the application will break.  Therefore, it's typically advised to make everything properties up-front, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You are only reusing the MyObj variable - think of it as a container. Each time you call this line

`obj = New MyObj`

You are creating a new `instance` of MyObj; therefore, your ArrayList will contain 10 different instances of MyObj.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code will work fine.  Each time you use the `New` operate you instantiate (create) a new object.  Therefore, each time through the loop, the `obj` variable will be re-assigned to reference a new object.

There are a couple of things, though, about your code which could be improved.  First, you should use `List(Of MyObj)` rather than `ArrayList`.  Second, it would be less confusing if you simply declared the `obj` variable inside of the loop, for instance:

```
Dim objects As New List(Of MyObj)()
For x As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim obj As New MyObj()
    obj.SomeValue = x
    objects.Add(obj)
Next
```

Comment: Wouldn't re-dimming the object every time cause it to take more time?

Comment: No.  The compiler will likely optimize the code to the same IL code anyway.  Even if it doesn't, the speed difference would be so negligible that it would be entirely insignificant.  In most situations, it's best to concern yourself with writing well designed, easy to read code.  Don't worry about performance issues until they become a problem.  If you were really worried about performance in every line of your code, you wouldn't be programming in .NET, you'd be programming in assembly.

Comment: Not only is concerning yourself with performance before it's a problem a waste of time, it also leads to harder to read and harder to maintain code.  In this case, the best-practice rule to follow is that variables should be declared in the narrowest scope possible.

Answer (score 0):

**10 Different Objects:**

```
Dim obj(9) as MyObj
Dim objarr New Generic.List(Of MyObj) 'As Neolisk Suggested in Original Post

For x as Integer = 0 to 9
     obj(x).SomeValue = x
     objarr.add(obj(x))
Next
```

**10 Different Instances of a same object:**

```
'-------Your Code------
Dim obj as MyObj
Dim objarr as New Arraylist

For x as Integer = 1 to 10
     obj = New MyObj
     obj.SomeValue = x
     objarr.add(obj)
Next
```

Comment: Your examples are both incorrect.  Try them.  The first one never instantiates the objects.  The second does create 10 different objects.